# Tap gesture recognizer interferes with URL taps in UITextView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextview

I have a disabled text view with a tap gesture recognizer attached to it. The problem is that this gesture recognizer intercepts all taps including those made on autodetected URLs (text view has data detectors turned on). Is there any way to prevent it from happening, so when a user taps an URL it's handled by text view itself (opening in Safari) and when a user taps somewhere else then my gesture recognizer is called?

Answer (score 3):

A bit hacky but it works:

```
if let recognizers = yourTextView.gestureRecognizers {
    for recognizer in recognizers {
        if recognizer.name == "UITextInteractionNameLinkTap" {
            myCustomTapGestureRecognizer.require(toFail: recognizer)
        }
    }
}
```

The name of the recognizer for detecting links is "UITextInteractionNameLinkTap"

Comment: Not hacky at all in my opinion! Nice work, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be if you could access the gesture recognizer used by the data detectors (then specifying that your tap recognizer should have lower priority than that one, by using the delegate's `gestureRecognizer:shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:` etc), but I don't think this is possible (anyone feel free to correct me here if I'm wrong).

Instead, you could try to add a delegate to the text view and check if the `textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:` was called during the active period of your gesture recognizer (then only run your handler when not handled by the `UITextView`).

Comment: I tried shouldInteractWithURL: but it's called only after a long press on an URL when it becomes highlighted. If a user just do a quick tap on an URL then this method is not called. 

Maybe it's a "feature" ie if you want to open an URL tap longer, otherwise you'll start editing. I actually started to prefer this behavior. Could be useful when you want to edit a long URL instead of opening it.

Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your textview is not a subview of other view.
If it is a subview, so add **UITextViewDelegate** for the top view and then add this one in **viewDidLoad**:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    yourTextview.delegate = self;
    yourTextview.editable = NO;
    yourTextview.selectable = YES;
    ...
}
```