# Not able to navigate on clicking a textview which is placed on top of a tableviewcell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, textview

I have a tableviewcell, in which I am displaying the title of an RSS feed, its date and the website name. Below this, I have a text field where I am displaying a short description. I want the user to be able to tap on any part of the tableviewcell to navigate to a new screen. At present, I am able to do that only when I tap on the part of the cell that has the title, date and website, but not on the part that has the textview with the description. Can I possibly implement such a thing?? If so how do I do it?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NewsCell *cell = (NewsCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"NewsViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.titleLabel.text = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"title"];

NSString *site = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"link"];

if ([site rangeOfString:@"dailymail"].location != NSNotFound) {
    site = @"Daily Mail";
}

else if (![site rangeOfString:@"theguardian"].location != NSNotFound){
    site = @"The Guardian";
}
else if (![site rangeOfString:@"football.co.uk"].location != NSNotFound) {
    site = @"Football UK";
}
else if (![site rangeOfString:@"football365"].location != NSNotFound) {
    site = @"Football 365";
}

cell.siteLabel.text = site;

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat: @"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:[[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"pubDate"]];

cell.pubDateLabel.text = dateString;

NSString *newsDescription = [[feeds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"description"];

CGRect textRect = [newsDescription boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(310,NSUIntegerMax) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]} context:nil];

CGSize stringSize = textRect.size;

textV=[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 50, 310, stringSize.height+25)];

for(UIView *subview in cell.contentView.subviews)
{
    if([subview isKindOfClass: [UITextView class]])
    {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}

if ([newsDescription isEqualToString:@""])
{
    newsDescription = @"Preview not available";

    textV.font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:12.0];

    textV.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
}
else
{
    textV.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];

    textV.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}

textV.text = newsDescription;

textV.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;


textV.editable = NO;

[cell.contentView addSubview:textV];


return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by having a look at the below post. Just set the textView userInteractionEnabled to NO.

[How to pass touch from a UITextView to a UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2478216/how-to-pass-touch-from-a-uitextview-to-a-uitableviewcell)